# jQuery selector AND operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

This may sound like a simple question, but I just cannot seem to find an answer on google, probably because the search term will bring back quite a lot of irrelevance.

I would like a jQuery selector to select all odd table rows, that are not in <thead> and apply a css class to them all.

```
table.cp-ss-grid tr:odd
```

The above selector will bring back all odd rows in the table correctly, but will include the thead rows (on ie)

How would I in the selector do an and, i.e. something like:

```
table.cp-ss-grid tr:odd:not(thead)
```

the above doesn't work and still brings back the thead rows

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not do:

```
$('table.cp-ss-grid > tbody > tr:odd');
```

To explicitly select the body rows? All browsers will add a tbody for you if you don't have one.

Comment: NB: Browsers will add tbody for HTML but not for XHTML. (XHTML served as text/html counts as HTML - one more reason why its a bad idea to do that)

Answer (score 11):

An `AND` selector for jQuery would be for example: `.classA.classB`

This would select elements which have classA and classB.

Answer (score 0):

if you use th to head and td to other rows ,
you can check that  the have child of td,

```
.children('td')
```

Answer (score 0):

`table.cp-ss-grid tr:odd` select all the odd rowb which will not include the header

if you want to specify a color of the header use  `:nth-child(n)`