# What does '>' do in jQuery find?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to decipher the following line of code

```
.find('> li ul:visible')
```

And I cannot figure out what '>' achieves.  I'm having trouble searching the documentation

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: Don't use it that way *(with no left operand to the `>`)*. That behavior will be deprecated. From the docs: *`Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it does is find all **direct** children of the current element based on the selector provided.

Let's say we have

```
<ul id="example">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul
```

If I searched for `$("#example").find('>li')` I would only find the two li's with Item 1 & Item 2. Since the `<li>` with Item3 is not a direct child from our target `<ul>` it is not matched.

Answer (score 0):

Its a definition for a child selector, the same as css e.g. see [jQuery selector AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047992/jquery-selector-and-operator) for how to select rows within a table body that aren't in the header.

Your example is finding a child element that is a list element

See also the API documentation http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ as suggested by @bzlm

Answer (score 0):

`>` Is a child selector, thus it finds the *visible* `ul` that is a *descendant* of `li` which is a  **direct** child of the selector...

> Child selector
>
> Description: Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

So when you `>` is in a `find` function, the parent is the element in the selector.

**BUT!! it's deprecated, as the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) says:**

> Note: The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.